# How to detect whether AzDO extension is running in YAML pipeline or Classic pipeline?

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

I've been googling around for this, but can't find anything.
Anyone knows a way to detect whether your extension is running in Classic vs YAML pipeline?

I'm working on an extension, which produces ANSI-colored output and apparently Classic pipeline logs UI can't deal with it, whereas YAML pipeline can. Instead of stripping colors completely I'm trying to find a way to be "smart" about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to detect whether AzDO extension is running in YAML pipeline or Classic pipeline?

I am afraid there is no such a way to limit the custom extension running in YAML pipeline or Classic pipeline at this moment.

What we can do at the moment is to add a state in the description of the extension:

```
{
    "id": "XXXX-A7C8-4A78-A7C3-8D717BB7C13C",
    "name": "YourExtension",
    "friendlyName": "Your Extension",
    "description": "This extension can only be used in YAML pipeline.",
```

In my opinion this is a reasonable demand, so I suggest that you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Comment: Liu - Thanks for the answer. I'm not saying I want to limit extension to one or another, just be able to programmatically detect whether AzDO is running my extension in Classic or YAML pipeline. That way I can format my output appropriate to the situation.

Comment: @favoretti, Thanks for your explanation. I got it, just like I said in my answer, There are currently no fields or attributes to limit the applicable scenarios of our extension, so we cannot judge whether the scenario we are currently in for extension is YAML or Classic mode based on valid fields or attributes.